# Gmail picking up parts of media-query styles (Mailchimp)

Tags: email, templates, gmail, media-queries, mailchimp

I'm finishing up a Mailchimp template and Gmail is the biggest headache now.

In my head I have some styles (css) and media queries. If I put the media-queries at the bottom - it stops most of the styles from getting through. If I put the media queries at the top - all my styles work perfectly but the mail looks "broken down" (like it should under 600px width / Mobile) like the media queries already kicked in.

Firstly I didn't think Gmail should read anything inside of a media-query and secondly why are is my mail shown "responsive" when I have full browser width?

---- on a side note ---- I know I can go through everything and add inline styles but, I have three templates and I'd rather not if I can get away with it :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11697326/595525

Comment: Gmail strips everything outside of the body tag, which includes style tags. Perhaps this unusual behavior is because you have the media query somewhere in the body? What you are describing sounds weird - you'll need to post code and screenshots if you want anyone to help resolve the situation. On the side note, you can work in the style tag, just run it through one of these [inlining tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code/17882057#17882057) before sending.

Comment: Yes. this is  strange. However, the CSS you write in mailchimp renders as inline when you send your campaigns. So I guess the issue is there? Is anyone familiar with the way Mailchimp works with the css styles in the head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out through extensive google-ing that I'm not the only one in the world that had this (weird) problem. I quote Lucas Mainardi below that posted an answer to a similar problem for Outlook.com.

**Basically, putting an extra style tag with your media queries just before the closing body tag will fix things.**

I've tested on my devices (gmail, iphone, thunderbird) and it doesn't seem to do any damage for clients that didn't have problems before. I'm also waiting for my Mailchimp inbox inspections to finish (where I test more clients like Outlook, Android etc). I'll edit my answer if it seems to do any harm, otherwise consider this a solution.

> Hello James,
>
> In the comments bellow I posted a possible solution to this issue in Outlook.com.
>
> The problem seems to be the area in which the email is loaded. Apparently, the area starts out in a small size and is resized a few seconds later, but in that time the media queries fire up and display the mobile version. This is because the media queries are read first in the hierarchy of the code (they're at the head section) and the HTML email is read second.
>
> The solution I found is to place the style section which contains the media queries after the HTML e-mail, specifically right above the closing body tag.
>
> I tried this out in Litmus and all seemed to work just fine across the board (no other browsers/mobile devices/e-mail servers seem to be affected negatively, displaying the exact same version of the email with the styles in the head section).

Taken from http://emailwizardry.nightjar.com.au/2013/08/28/media-queries-in-html-email-cover-all-your-bases/